# Problems with uuid node package ( creating todo list )

Tags: reactjs

I am studding react and having difficulties with uuid package.

I am using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nUl5QLkVdvU

And the error:

```
TypeError: uuid_v4__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default.a.v4 is not a function

  15 |    function handleSubmit(e){
  16 |        e.preventDefault();
  17 |        if (todo.task.trim()) {
> 18 |            addTodo({ ...todo, id: uuid.v4() });
     | ^  19 |            setTodo({ ...todo, task: "" });
  20 |        }
  21 |
```

All code from TodoForm.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import uuid from "uuid/v4";

function TodoForm( addTodo ) {
    const [todo, setTodo] = useState({
        id: "",
        task: "",
        completed: false
    });

    function handleTaskInputChange(e){
        setTodo({ ...todo, task: e.target.value});
    }

    function handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if (todo.task.trim()) {
            addTodo({ ...todo, id: uuid.v4() });
            setTodo({ ...todo, task: "" });
        }

    }
    return(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input 
                name="task"
                type="text"
                value={todo.task}
                onChange={handleTaskInputChange} />
            <button type="submit">submit</button>
        </form>
    );
}

export default TodoForm;
```

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `import` this way:

```
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

Then you can use the function this way:

```
uuidv4();
```

In your case:

```
...
if (todo.task.trim()) {
   addTodo({ ...todo, id: uuidv4() });
   setTodo({ ...todo, task: "" });
}
...
```

You can also try to change your code this way when you don't change the `import`, but then I'm not 100% sure, if it works:

```
...
if (todo.task.trim()) {
   addTodo({ ...todo, id: uuid() });
   setTodo({ ...todo, task: "" });
}
...
```

But give it a try...

Comment: I tried this but now I am having this error: ```TypeError: addTodo is not a function```

Comment: Yes, but this is a different issue. You did not specify `addTodo`. You just specified `setTodo` in your code.

Comment: I will check everything again and will give some feedback later. Here is the exercise by the way: https://github.com/samgamage/todo-react

Comment: Yes, please don't forget to mark as accepted answer if it worked for you. The other error is a different issue

Comment: Yes it did, thank you for the answer. About another error. I did some research, reinstalled react, uuid and found out that the issue was with my react (node) version. Really strange bug by the way.